# add sound to gallery image with array in Eclipse

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse, audio, image-gallery

i'm from indonesia so sorry for my bad english. i have a source code like below :
public class LihatHuruf extends Activity {

```
MediaPlayer soundofletter;
int indeks=0;
String[] letter = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
int [] sound = {R.raw.a , R.raw.b , R.raw.c , R.raw.d , R.raw.e , R.raw.f ,
                R.raw.g , R.raw.h , R.raw.i , R.raw.j , R.raw.k , R.raw.l ,
                R.raw.m , R.raw.n , R.raw.o , R.raw.p , R.raw.q , R.raw.r ,
                R.raw.s , R.raw.t , R.raw.u , R.raw.v , R.raw.w , R.raw.x , R.raw.y , R.raw.z};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.lihathuruf);

    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(LihatHuruf.this, "" + letter[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}




public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
    TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
    mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
            R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
    a.recycle();
}

public int getCount() {
    return mImageIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

    i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
    i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(250, 300));
    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
     return i;
}
```

}
}

the program output is if i click an image(letter A) so it will show the toast a letter of A. BUT i want change the array of letter with an array with my audio in res/raw . I dont know exactly the code, maybe anybody can give me the code, every answer is very helpfull for me. Thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the MediaPlayer class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Something like this in your `OnItemClick` method should do the trick:

```
MediaPlayer player=MediaPlayer.create(LihatHuruf.this, sound[position]);
player.start();
```

Comment: it's 100% work on my project, thank you gdros for your answer, it's really help me :)